# Has the Erdős space the structure of a monothetic topological group?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

This question is motivated by this [MO-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302724/automorphisms-of-erd%C3%B6s-spaces/302839#302839) asking if the Erdős spaces $\mathfrak E$ and $\mathfrak E_c$ admit a self-homeomorphism with dense orbits of points.

The affirmative answer would follow from the affirmative answer to the following

> **Problem.** Are the Erdős spaces $\mathfrak E$ and $\mathfrak E_c$ homeomorphic to monothetic topological groups?

Now I recall the necessary definitions. A topological group $G$ is *monothetic* if it contains a dense cyclic subgroup. Many examples of monothetic topological groups can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9907128.pdf).

The subspaces
$$\mathfrak E:=\{(x_n)_{n\in\omega}\in\ell_2:\forall n\in\omega\;\;x_n\in\mathbb Q\}$$
and
$$\mathfrak E_c:=\{(x_n)_{n\in\omega}\in\ell_2:\forall n\in\omega\;\;x_n\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\}$$
of the real separable Hilbert space are called the *rational Erdős space* and the *complete Erdős space*, respectively. The rational Erdős space $\mathfrak E$ is a subgroup of $\ell_2$ and the complete Erdős space $\mathfrak E_c$ is homeomorphic to the closed subgroup $$G:=\{(x_n)_{n\in\omega}\in\ell_2:\forall n\in\omega\;\; x_n\in\tfrac1{2^n}\mathbb Z\}$$ by Theorem 4.11 of [Dijkstra and van Mill](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/629c/6bde87b1296d3b76a526ee99e31e32068770.pdf).

However the subgroups  $\mathfrak E$ and $G$ of $\ell_2$ are not monothetic.

Comment: Is there a typo in the title?

Comment: @WlodAA Yes, there was a typo (now correcetd by Alon Amit, I hope). Tahnk you for noticing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to supply some useful constructions, with a hope that they would help to solve the problems proposed by Taras (possibly, by an analogy rather than directly).

> $\mathbf{\ell^2}$**-product of arbitrary metric spaces**

The following construction must be classical. Let $\ (X_n\ d_n)\ $ be
metric spaces; let $\ p_n\in X_n;\ $ and let
$\ \mathbf X_n:=((X_n\ d_n)\ p_n).\ $ Define $\ m^2(\mathbf X)\ $ to be the set of all square summable sequences
$\ x:=(x_1\ x_2\ \ldots)\in \prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n,\ $ meaning that
$\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n^2(x_n\ p_n) < \infty.\ $ The Euclid-Hilbert
distance $\ \delta\ $ in $\ m^2(\mathbf X)\ $ is given by

$$ \delta(x\ y):=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n^2(x_n\ y_n)}, $$

for $\ x:=(x_1\ x_2\ \ldots)\ $ and $\ y:=(y_1\ y_2\ \ldots),\ $
but of course.

---

**Remark**   Let's consider the special case $\ \mathbf X_1=\mathbf X_2=\ldots.\ $
Then $\,\ m^2(\mathbf X)\,\ $ and
$\,\ m^2(\mathbf X)\times m^2(\mathbf X)\,\ $ are homeomorphic as topological spaces. Furthermore, we may introduce the Euclid-Hilbert
metrics in the latter space to make the two spaces **isometric**.

> **An example of a monothetic group**

Let $\ p_1<p_2\ldots\ $ be the sequence of all primes, and let
$\ \forall_n\ q_n=p_n^2.\ $ Define a distance $\ d_n\ $ in
$\ X_n:= \mathbb Z_{q_n}:=\{0\ \ldots\ q_n\!-\!1\}\ $ as follows:

$$ d_n(s\ t)\ :=\ \frac 1{p_n}\cdot\min(\,|s-t|\ \ \ q_n\!-\!|s\!-\!t|\,) $$

Then we may introduce Euclid-Hilbert distance in the group
$\ \mathbf X\ :=\ \prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n.\ $ Element

$$ (1\ 1\ \ldots)\ \in \mathbf X $$

generates a dense (cyclic) subgroup--in other words, group $\ \mathbf X\ $ is monothetic.